# External display set brightness with laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, external-display

I have Dell U2415 connect to my laptop. On laptop I can manage brightnes with fn + arrow, but this work only on laptop. It show windows show

[image]

But dell not react is there some application can do this? Drivers not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I set extrnal display brightness?

You need to install the [Dell Display Manager](http://sur.ly/o/dell.com/support%2Fdrivers%2Fus%2Fen%2F19%2Fdriverdetails%3Fdriverid%3D9YJ4T/AA001290).

---

#### Dell Display Manager

> Dell Display Manager is a Microsoft Windows application used to manage a monitor or a
>   group of monitors. It allows manual adjustment of the displayed image, assignment of
>   automatic settings, energy management, window organization, image rotation, and
>   other features on select Dell monitors. Once
>   installed, Dell Display Manager runs each
>   time the system starts and places its icon
>   in the notification tray. Information about
>   monitors connected to the system is available when hovering over the notification-tray
>   icon.
>
> **Using the Quick Settings Dialog**
>
> Clicking Dell Display Manager's notification tray icon opens the Quick
>   Settings dialog box. When more than one supported Dell monitors are
>   connected to the computer, a specific target monitor can be selected
>   using the menu. **The Quick Settings dialog box allows you to easily
>   adjust the brightness, contrast, resolution, window layout, and so
>   on.** It also allows you to enable automatic switching between preset
>   modes or to select a preset mode manually.

Source [Dell Display Manager User’s Guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_display_projector/esuprt_Display/dell-u2415_User%27s%20Guide2_en-us.pdf):

Comment: The monitor listed in the question is not supported with DDM?

Comment: @Psycogeek really? According to http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-u2415/manuals it is ...

Comment: Ok "Dell Display Manager Software included (comes in the CD shipped with the monitor)."  I guess it just isn't in the compatability list for the program itself, or on the monitors downloads list the same way it is for the ones in the compatability list.   It also does not show support for win8.  It is just the usual badly updated web stuff.  I was interested because my dell might have worked with that.